# window.Open causes new window to appear behind parent

Tags: javascript, browser

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to prevent IE from popping up child windows behind the parent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried giving the new window focus?

```
newwindow = window.open(...);
if (window.focus) {
    newwindow.focus();
}
```

Comment: I did try this and it didn't work.  It is still opening behind the parent.

Comment: Maybe try delaying it a bit. `setTimeout("newwindow.focus()", 1000);`

Comment: It's just an issue of timing. First, `window.open()` executes. And `newwindow.focus()` executes immediately after that, whether or not `newwindow` has fully loaded. By calling `setTimeout()`, you give `newwindow` a chance to load before trying to give it focus.